# How do I evaulate a procedure that's returned as a symbol

Tags: scheme

We are dealing with data representation in my class and we had to represent the integers as diff trees.  For my is-zero? class I want to actually evaluate the diff-tree to see if it comes out to 0.  However all of my procedures return symbols.  I don't know how to make Scheme evaluate the procedures.

diff-tree ::= (one) | (diff diff-tree diff-tree)

(predecessor '(one)) = (diff (one)(one))

So if I have `(is-zero? (predecessor '(one)))`         |note: it has to take it in as a symbol

it will evaluate to (is-zero? '(diff (one)(one)))
how do I get it so that I can actually evaluate the diff as a function?
I already have (define diff -) (define (one) 1) so if I just run (diff (one)(one))

All the other functions, such as predecessor, have to return a symbol.

I'm not very good at explaining but I hope I've done a good enough job for people to understand.

NOTE: I've created another function the recursively runs through the diff tree and evaluates it.  It's not as nice as I would have liked it but it will work.

```
(define evaluate
  (lambda (dt)
    (if (eqv? (car dt) 'diff)
        (- (evaluate (cadr dt))(evaluate (caddr dt)))
        1
        )))
(define is-zero?
  (lambda (dt)
    (if (= 0 (evaluate dt))
        #t
        #f
     )))
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a sketch, No access to a Scheme compiler :).

```
(define (list-eval l)
  (apply (car l) (map list-eval (cdr l))))

(define (is-zero? l)
  (= 0 (list-eval l)))
```

Comment: Thanks.  I had forgotten about the apply and map procedures.

Comment: you cannot apply a symbol, only a procedure. if, as the OP says, it's a symbol, then you need to `eval` it to get the procedure before you can apply it

Comment: Oog, yuck. Don't use eval. Your professor won't like it (I wouldn't).

Answer (score 0):

It sure looks to me like the idea of this assignment is for you either to develop an interpreter for diff-trees or (given the "interesting"ness of the specification) to develop functions that perform algebraic manipulations on trees that preserve "meaning."

Assuming that it's all right to just write an interpreter that returns an integer--this is clearly what you have in mind--you need to develop the straightforward (from the appropriate [HtDP](http://www.htdp.org) chapter) "function on a piece of self-referential compound data" (that is, your diff trees). It starts by picking a name and contract for your "interpret" function. Then, how about some test cases?

Comment: The assignment was to define a representation of all integers as diff-trees.  I then had to turn that representation into an implementation making the zero, is-zero?, predecessor, and successor functions.  At first I was defining is-zero? by checking to see if both children were equal to each other but with the diff-tree implementation, there are an infinite number of ways to represent each number(1 can be represented as (diff 1 0), (diff 2 1), (diff 3 2), etc.  So the only way I know of to check to see if something is zero is to actually evaluate to diff-tree.

Comment: Okay, sounds good. So you want to develop an interpreter, that maps diff-trees to numbers.  Per my earlier suggestion: pick a name, write the contract (hint: it appears in the prior sentence). Then, write some test cases.